# How do I get a function to accept a String or an Array of Strings?

Tags: swift

I feel like this is a "generics" thing, but I can't figure out how others do it? I'm pretty sure in Typescript I just do `String|String[]` but not sure how it works in Swift. Here's my attempt:

```
func HiWorld(passedVar: String|[String]){
   print(passedVar)
}
```

or

```
func HiWorld<T, String|[String]>(passedVar: T){
   print(passedVar)
}
```

Comment: Might consider only keeping the `String` version. `Array.map(_:)` and `Array.forEach(_:)` let you convert every function that takes a single element into a function that can take an array of elements, without needing multiple overloads

Comment: @Alexander thanks for the recommendation. For my use case, I ended up creating two optional variables on the same func, one that accepts a String? and one that accepts a [String]? and rejecting if both are nil. It's a bit of an oddball use case for sure and would be safer if I just did the wrapper function recommendation like Rob suggested.

Comment: `and rejecting if both are nil` That's probably a misplaced responsibility. Unwrapping optionals should be done on the caller's side, not in the callee.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're describing is an overload. You just express it as two functions, where one chains to the more general version.

```
// Specialized version; a one-element list
func hiWorld(passedVar: String) {
   hiWorld(passedVar: [passedVar])
}

// general version; list of any length
func hiWorld(passedVar: [String]) {
   print(passedVar)
}
```

(In practice, this is often how you wind up implementing it in TypeScript as well, since you can't generally do the same things with all types. Your `print` example is very special and misleading case.)

The syntax you're describing is an algebraic data type, and Swift doesn't support that syntax directly. While it can be a convenient shortcut, Swift generally prefers using an explicit enum or a protocol in cases where this kind of overload wouldn't make sense.

Comment: Thanks for the context, super helpful.